# Replace leading character with equal number of another character

Tags: python

I need to replace leading dots in a string with spaces.

E.g., `".....Some string."` into `"     Some string."`

What is a good (fast) way to do it?

I came up with:

```
n = len(s)
s = s.lstrip(".")
s = " " * (n - len(s)) + s
```

I am not very familiar with regex. Is there a way to do it using "re"?

Comment: Your solution is probably good enough for most use cases Using regex is almost certainly overkill and since strings are immutable in python looping through and replacing as you go will be even less performant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression.

**Method 1** - use `re.sub` with a callback to match all the dots in the beginning of the string, and replace them with a string containing an equal amount of spaces.

```
re.sub(r"^\.+", lambda dots: ' ' * len(dots.group(0)), '.....Some string.')
```

**Method 2** - a shorter but more cryptic expression:

```
re.sub(r"\.([^.].*)?", r' \1', ".....Some string.")
```

This works because `re.sub` scans for dots starting at index 0. As long as it find dots that only have other dots after them, it just replaces them with spaces. When it reaches the last dot, it doesn't have another dot after it so the expression matches the rest of the string including the last dot, and replaces it with `r' \1'`, which means 'a space and whatever came after it inside the brackets'